# sending post data(geojson) jquery in asp.net core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, openlayers

using openlayers to get location from map.

get coordinates like this

[32.80144214630127, 39.96892690658569]

need to seperate them into latitude and longitude to post

```
function savetodb() {
    // get array of all features 
    var featureArray = drawSource.getFeatures()
    // Define geojson format 
    var geogJONSformat = new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    // Use method to convert feature to geojson
    var featuresGeojson = geogJONSformat.writeFeaturesObject(featureArray)
    // Array of all geojson
    var geojsonFeatureArray = featuresGeojson.features

    for (i = 0; i < geojsonFeatureArray.length; i++) {

        console.log(geojsonFeatureArray[i].geometry.coordinates)
    }
```

posting line

```
$.post({
        url: "https://localhost:44330/Products",
        data: {
            "name": "string",
            "latitude": 0,
            "longitude":0 
        }
    })
```

couldnt figure it out how to put these coordinates into latitude and longitude lines

Answer (score 0):

Just map the array elements to an object then use it with `$.post`

```
var featureArray = drawSource.getFeatures()
var geogJONSformat = new ol.format.GeoJSON()
var featuresGeojson = geogJONSformat.writeFeaturesObject(featureArray)
var geojsonFeatureArray = featuresGeojson.features

const keys = ['latitude', 'longitude']

let data = Object.assign(...geojsonFeatureArray
                     .map((el, i) => ({ [keys[i]]: el.geometry.coordinates })))

$.post({
    url: "https://localhost:44330/Products",
    data: data
})
```